How do I make WebStorm close the processes, in the terminal, when I exit?
I am developing an app using React Native Expo as the frontend, and NodeJS (Hono) as the backend.
my IDE is now WebStorm (I switched from VS Code a week ago).
after the transition from VS code, I get this issue - Every time I exit WebStrom without closing the frontend and backend processes in the terminal, once I reopen WebStorm, I find that the frontend and backend ports are already taken by other processes.
this is how it looks:


here is the text:
node:events:498
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:5000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1904:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1961:12)
    at doListen (node:net:2135:7)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1940:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 5000
}

Node.js v22.4.0

 Port 8081 is being used by another process
√ Use port 8082 instead?

What can be done to tackle this?
I tried:

closing the processes in the windows task managager. It works, but I hate doing it every time.
tried disabling autosave. didn't help.
tried to kill the processes using "netstat -ano | findstr :8081" and "taskkill /PID  /F". It works, but I have to do it every time.
ensuring the option "Close session when it ends" in WebStorm is checked. doesn't help.
looked for auto-run project scripts in WebStorm. there are none..


For future users with the same problem - the issue resolved once I disabled WebStorm's new terminal
